# variable cant store the random int

Tags: python

I am having trouble with this code the result is not working it always shows incorrect here's the code

```
# A program to make multiplication questions
import random

# takes a random no. from 1 to 50

no1 = random.randint(1, 50)
no2 = random.randint(1, 50)

result = no1 * no2

question = f"what is {no1} x {no2} ?"
print(question)

answer = input("what is the answer? ")

if answer == result:
    print("you found the correct answer")
else:
    print("incorrect")
```

I was trying to make a math question program which asks you random multiplication questions.

but the result variable didn't store the result or something else went wrong.

Comment: `input` returns a `str`, not an `int`.